# Border-gradient на CSS. Может ли кто показать?

Tags: css

Приветствую

```
//представим
border-top:1px solid #999999;
```

Обычная горизонтальная полоска, серого цвета. Можно ли сделать градиент? Допустим начиная с серого переходя в белый

p.s. да, признаюсь, я негодник гуглил. Есть рамки на все 4 стороны, есть JS, есть еще фон, поверх него накладываем свой фон, получается 'как бы то, что надо'. Простых решений не видел

Comment: Не нужно никаких фильтров и прочего хлама. Все делается довольно легко. В этом [видео](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KAfTPK869OY) дословно показано и рассказано как сделать градиент у рамки.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Используйте псевдо-элементы с заливкой градиентом вместо бордеров.

**[Посмотреть пример](http://jsfiddle.net/venzell/2QLL8/)**

Верстка

```
<div class="gradient-demo"></div>
```

CSS

```
.gradient-demo::before {
    /* Градиент */
    background: #ffffff;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #ffffff 0%, #999999 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%, #ffffff), color-stop(100%, #999999));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #ffffff 0%, #999999 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(left, #ffffff 0%, #999999 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, #ffffff 0%, #999999 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #ffffff 0%, #999999 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#999999', GradientType=1);
    content: "";
    display: block;
    /* Вместо толщины */
    height: 3px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Пример шикарный!

Answer (score 2):

можно еще так

```
background: rgb(30, 50, 230);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(30deg, rgb(30, 50, 230) 30%, rgb(90, 140, 250) 70%);
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(30deg, rgb(30, 50, 230) 30%, rgb(90, 140, 250)  70%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(30deg, rgb(30, 50, 230) 30%, rgb(90, 140, 250) 70%);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(30deg, rgb(30, 50, 230) 30%, rgb(90, 140, 250) 70%);
background: linear-gradient(120deg, rgb(30, 50, 230) 30%, rgb(90, 140, 250) 70%);
```

а вообще http://css3gen.com/gradient-generator/ ссыль