# Возможно ли реализовать на css, такой border

Tags: html, css, css3

[image: Border залит градиентом]

Возможно ли на css залить градиентом, такой border?

Comment: Чтобы при этом оставить прозрачность в центре - нет

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Border-gradient на CSS. Может ли кто показать?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/301848/border-gradient-%d0%bd%d0%b0-css-%d0%9c%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский в том вопросе необходимо сделать градиентный border лишь с какой-то одной стороны. А в данном же вопросе нужно залить градиентом рамку со всех сторон

Comment: Да нужна прозрачность в центре.

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант можно сделать так

```
<div class="bordered">button</div>

.bordered {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 8px 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  color: rgba(0,0,200,.3);
  border: 4px solid #000;
  border-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #3acfd5 0%, rgba(0,0,200,.3) 100%) 4;
}
```

Но есть недостатки:

1 - текст не оформлен градиентом, можно конечно сделать, но работать будет только в хроме;

2 - нет скругления углов.

Здесь пример - https://jsfiddle.net/bwe4vjsz/

Comment: Конечно нужно скругленные, углы, но большое спасибо что прислали хороший код, прием конечно известный) Ставлю плюсик